# Can you explain $.fancybox.open( [group], [options] ) params and if I can add youtube link as href?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm reading documentation:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

and the $.fancybox.open( [group], [options] ) and open explanation is good, but I'm wondering if I can use a link to a youtube video in the group array? I'm attempting to play a youtube video after the dom is ready such as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
        title : '1st title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
        title : '2nd title'
    }    
], {
    padding : 0   
});
```

I am able to get my video to appear in a fancybox, which is great, but I want it to appear after the page loads automatically without the need to click on a link, such as the fancybox does in the jsfiddle example above with .open.

Thank you for all of your help in advance.

Comment: They have an example of their blog, its example number 4 at http://fancybox.net/blog and if you want to have this happen after the dom is loaded try doing it inside `$(function () { //YOUR CODE HERE });`

Comment: Thank you. Isn't that example using a previous version of fancyBox?

Comment: you can actually use a hidden <a> tag and trigger an click event on page load.

Comment: @gabemartinez Check out my updated answer and see if thats what you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried doing this yet?

```
$(function () {
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
            type: 'iframe',
            href : 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque',                
            title : '1st title'
        }
    ], {
        padding : 0
    });
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NDM5F/

Comment: Yes sir, I have. And that works fine with images. Just attempting to have a YouTube link or a swf that is hosted by us load instead.

Comment: Steven, you are a beast! Thank you very much. I also want to thank Calvin for the help and his suggestion did work, I just wanted to use the fancybox.open. Much appreciated, all.

Comment: Just in case anyone was looking for the working example of this fancyBox YouTube popup: http://houstonfootballstadium.com/home/