# How open youtube video manually with fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I am building an angularJS webapp and I want to open a youtube video by calling a method of my constructor. To achieve that; I want to reproduce the same behavior as

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'fade',
                closeEffect : 'fade',
                padding: 0,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });
    });
```

But using the manual  way, `$.fancybox.open([ ... ])`. Can someone guide me on how to do it?

Comment: Maybe this post helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948019/can-you-explain-fancybox-open-group-options-params-and-if-i-can-add-yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.fancybox.open({
    content: '<iframe width="xxx" height="xxx" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the full `iframe` HTML tag as `content` in the fancybox API options but passing the video's URL and set the `type` to `iframe`. You could simply do :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.fancybox.open({
        href: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/jid2A7ldc_8",
        type: "iframe",
        // other API options
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        padding: 0,
        helpers: {
            buttons: {}
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xc0coft4/1/)**