# Timing fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a popup window using fancybox which I would like to add some timings to, show after 1 second maybe and disappear after 5. I cant figure out where to add any delays in the code i am using, please can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($popup) {
        $popup("#hidden_link").fancybox({
            onComplete: function () {
                $popup("#fancybox-img").wrap($popup("<a />", {
                    href: "mylink.html",
                    target: "_blank",
                    // delay: 9000 would like a delay ideally 
                }));           
            }
        }).trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```

```html
<a id="hidden_link" href="images/myimage.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.fancybox.open()`, see details here - [Can you explain $.fancybox.open( [group], [options] ) params and if I can add youtube link as href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948019/can-you-explain-fancybox-open-group-options-params-and-if-i-can-add-yo), and `$.fancybox.close()`.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.fancybox.open(...)
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $.fancybox.close(...)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: the potential issue is that the `$.fancybox.close()` will be triggered even **before** fancybox is opened ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your link is not going to be visible, you may rather open fancybox programmatically using the `$.fancybox.open()` method and close it using the `$.fancybox.close()` method.

As pointed out, you could use `setTimeout()` to delay the execution of either those methods like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($popup) {
    // open with delay
    setTimeout(function () {
        $popup.fancybox({
            href: 'images/image01.jpg',
            onComplete: function () {
                $popup("#fancybox-img").wrap($popup("<a />", {
                    href: "mylink.html",
                    target: "_blank"
                }));
                // close with delay
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $popup.fancybox.close();
                }, 9000); // setTimeout close
            }
        });
    }, 2000); // setTimeout open
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6f507ws2/)**

**Note**: this is for fancybox v1.3.4.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, this one worked great :-)